# Expected to find ) for map function as iterable

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting an error in dart when I use the map function as iterable.

```
Future _addPostMedia() {
debugLog('Adding post media');

return Future.wait(_data.remainingCompressedMediaToUpload
.map(_uploadPostMediaItem as Function(File e)) as Iterable<Future>
.toList());}
```

> Above I'm getting an error Expected to find ) just before the
> .toList()

This was the original code which wasn't working and VSCode recommend some fixes :

Future _compressPostMedia() {
debugLog('Compressing post media');

```
return Future.wait(
    _data.remainingMediaToCompress.map(_compressPostMediaItem)
    .toList());}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each level of casting needs to wrapped in its set of parenthesis, so you were missing a set wrapping the as Iterable.

```
Future _addPostMedia() {
  debugLog('Adding post media');

  return Future.wait(
    _data.remainingCompressedMediaToUpload.map(
      (_uploadPostMediaItem as Function(File e)) as Iterable<Future>
    ).toList()
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi. In my case after attempting the above : I get "The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<Future<dynamic>>'." With a Quick fix to Cast it adds another ''as Iterable<Future>" beside the one already existing.

Comment: what if instead of Iterable<Future> do List<Future>

Comment: Yup worked. I'm adding the final one to your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Could you please check my answer. Need to know if I'm the right track.

Comment: if it works, then it is good. but just looking at, looks fine

Comment: yup, no problem, casting things is always "joy" in every language lol

Answer (score 1):

Based on discussions with @Cstark, the following steps is what made the error disappear:

Attempted:

```html
Future _addPostMedia() {   debugLog('Adding post media');

  return Future.wait(
    _data.remainingCompressedMediaToUpload.map(
      (_uploadPostMediaItem as Function(File e)) as List<Future>));}
```

Vscode suggested a cast as a quick fix and the following is the final code:

```html
Future _addPostMedia() {
  debugLog('Adding post media');

  return Future.wait(
    _data.remainingCompressedMediaToUpload.map(
      (_uploadPostMediaItem as Function(File e)) as Future<Object?> Function(File e))
  );
}
```